# Using Neural Network program to predict stock prices

Tags: python, neural-network, gradient-descent

I've attempted to write a Neural Network. I have a downloaded [.csv file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/edobjnnunf87y4l/price_data.csv?dl=0) containing the starting time and closing prices of certain cryptocurrency stock; and I hope to create a predictive model.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, width, activation_function):
        self.width=width
        # activation function = 'Sigmoid' , 'ReLu')
        self.activation_function=activation_function
        # number of hidden layers
        self.depth=len(width)-2
        # Weight matrix
        self.W= np.array([np.random.randn(self.width[i+1],self.width[i]) for i in range(self.depth+1)], dtype=object)
        # bais vector
        self.b= np.array([np.random.randn(self.width[i+1]) for i in range(self.depth+1)], dtype=object)
        #learning rate
        self.alpha = 0.1 

    def sigma(self,x):
        if self.activation_function == 'Sigmoid':
            return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
        else:
            if x.any()>=0:
                return x
            else:
                return 0

    def d_sigma(self,x):
        if self.activation_function == 'Sigmoid':
            return self.sigma(x)*self.sigma(1-x)
        else:
            if x>=0:
                return 1
            else:
                return 0

  ## vectorize the function
    def sigma_vec(self,X):
        return np.array([self.sigma(x) for x in X],dtype=np.float128)
    def d_sigma_vec(self,X):
        return np.array([self.d_sigma(x) for x in X],dtype=np.float128)

    def h(self,x):  
        a=np.copy(self.b)  
        z=np.copy(self.b)
        z[0]=np.dot(self.W[0],x)+self.b[0]
        for i in range(self.depth):
            a[i]=self.sigma_vec(z[i])
            z[i+1]=np.dot(self.W[i+1],a[i])+self.b[i+1]
        return z[-1]

    def plot(self,plt,X,col):
        dx = np.linspace(X[0],X[len(X)-1], 100)
        h_dx = np.array([ self.h([x]) for x in dx],dtype=np.float128)
        plt.plot(dx,h_dx,color=col)

    def plot0(self,plt,col):
        dx = np.linspace(0,1, 100)
        h_dx = np.array([ self.h([x]) for x in dx],dtype=np.float128)
        plt.plot(dx,h_dx,color=col)

    def gradient_of_loss_function(self,h,y):
        return h-y

    def gradient(self,x,y):
        a=np.copy(self.b)
        z=np.copy(self.b)
        z[0]=np.dot(self.W[0],x)+self.b[0]
        for i in range(self.depth):
            a[i]=self.sigma_vec(z[i])
            z[i+1]=np.dot(self.W[i+1],a[i])+self.b[i+1]
            gradient_b=np.copy(self.b)
            gradient_W=np.copy(self.W)
            gradient_b[-1]=self.gradient_of_loss_function(z[-1],y)
            for i in reversed(range(self.depth)):
                gradient_b[i]=np.dot(np.transpose(self.W[i+1]),gradient_b[i+1])*self.d_sigma_vec(z[i])
                gradient_W[i+1]=np.outer(gradient_b[i+1],a[i])
                gradient_W[0]=np.outer(gradient_b[0],x)
        return gradient_b,gradient_W;

    def batch_gradient(self,X,Y):
        batch_gradient_W=0
        batch_gradient_b=0
        for i in range(len(X)):
            gradient_b,gradient_W = self.gradient(X[i],Y[i])
            batch_gradient_W += gradient_W
            batch_gradient_b += gradient_b
        return batch_gradient_b,batch_gradient_W;

    def train(self,X,Y,iterate):
        for i in range(iterate):
            alpha= self.alpha/len(X)
            batch_gradient_b,batch_gradient_W =self.batch_gradient(X,Y)
            self.W -= alpha*batch_gradient_W
            self.b -= alpha*batch_gradient_b
```

```
with open(mergedcsv, newline='') as csvfile:
    rows=csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in rows:
        i=i+1
    print(i)
UsePercent = 1
datanum=i
with open(mergedcsv, newline='') as csvfile:
    i=1
    rows=csv.reader(csvfile)
    data = []
    data_axis = []
    putime = []
    hide_data = []
    hide_data_axis = []
    hide_putime = []
    time=0
    for row in rows:
 #       if i <=4 and i>1:
        if i<=2:
            i=i+1
            continue;
        i=i+1
        if(i>datanum*UsePercent):
            try:
                hide_data.append(round(float(row[5]),2))
                time= float(row[1])
                time = int(time/1000)
                hide_data_axis.append(time)
                hide_putime.append(i)
            except ValueError:
                print("",end="")
                print(time)
            continue
        try:
            data.append(round(float(row[5]),2))
            time= float(row[1])
            time = int(time/1000)
            data_axis.append(time)
            putime.append(i)
        except ValueError:
            print("",end="")
            print(time)
```

What are the suitable variables I need to create a model? Here is one I have tried; it leads to an overflow error due to the sigmoid activation function's exponential power formula. I would appreciate suggestions on what a suitable X-axis input, Y-axis input, and width.

```
Y= (np.array(data, dtype=np.float128).reshape(-1,1))[:28] #data = array of closing prices
X= (np.array(data_axis, dtype=np.float128).reshape(-1,1))[:28] #data_axis is an array representing the time

width=[1,5,3,1]
nn=NeuralNetwork(width,'Sigmoid')

plt.scatter(X,Y,color='r')
nn.plot0(plt,'b')
nn.train(X,Y,10)
nn.plot0(plt,'g')
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt that such a prediction will work, because the reason for the change is not in the dataset - and probably will never be. Reasons for price changes are likely in the news.

Answer (score 0):

As @ThomasWeller already mentioned: Training on the closing prices only will not lead to a good performance of your model. You will have to take additional data into account. Like Google-Trends / Twitter / News.

In addition i wonder why you don't take a framework like **Pytorch** or **Tensorflow**?

Comment: I have not used either of those frameworks. Someone else offered to help me and used Pytorch, but we are both stuck with returned errors (they also used closing prices as a model.) Should I perhaps start fresh, from a relevant approach?

Comment: I would recommend that to be honest. On Github you will find good examples to start with one of those frameworks.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Is there any point in trying to fix the overflow errors this piece of code is returning? I'm concerned because these overflow/invalid-value error does not happen with randomized/generated data created in the program (cosine function + noise is one which works) but has continuously happened with data from imported files, even after rounding floating points or changed array dtype to np.float128. I've made sure the data is not corrupted, NumPy can run a successful linear regression on it